# Application for scanning picture

Tags: vb.net, twain

How to implement Twain OCX in VB.NET project for scanning or loading pictures?

Comment: I'll keep it short too.  Twain is hopelessly obsolete, use WIA.

Answer (score 0):

There's a free version of [EZTwain](http://www.dosadi.com/eztwain1.htm), or if you have money to spend there's [DotTwain](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/dottwain),  (full disclosure I work for Atalasoft), or there is also this new-ish project http://code.google.com/p/twaindotnet/